# Simple Schema minDate maxDate

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I think this is a simple question. I'm using simple schema and I want to have a minDate and maxDate. The documentation talks about it in validation section but I'm not sure how to define it in the schema itself. Any help would be great. Thanks

Path: `Schema.js`

```
startDate: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
          }
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an issue in the [simple-schema repo](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/20) that goes over this.  Here's how your code might look with a static min/max date:

```
startDate: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    min: new Date(2016, 1, 1),
    autoform: {
        type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
    }
},
endDate: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    max: new Date(2018, 1, 1),
    autoform: {
        type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
    }
}
```

You can use the `custom` validator if you want to make those dates dynamic.  Here's [a link](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#custom-validation) to the relevant documentation.  Your start date would look something like this:

```
startDate: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    custom: function() {
        var myMinDate = new Date(); //today
        if(myMinDate > this.value) {
            return 'minDate';  //Error string according to the docs.
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    autoform: {
        type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
    }
},
endDate: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    custom: function() {
        var myMaxDate = new Date(2018, 11, 31); //Last day of 2018
        if(myMaxDate < this.value) {
            return 'maxDate';  //Error string according to the docs.
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    autoform: {
        type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. How do reference the endDate in the custom function?

Comment: Sorry. What I meant was how do I reference the endDate that the user adds. As in if (startDate > endDate) {
            return 'minDate';  //Error string according to the docs.
        } else {
            return true;
        }

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying.  I just had to do that for my project actually - I did it client-side in my event.  I just took the datepicker values and compared them.  If startDate > endDate, I threw an error and didn't execute any server side logic.

Comment: Will that error if they don't have client side validation running, for instance they're using an old browser?

Comment: No, you're not using jQuery validation in that case, you're using code to validate and inform the user on error.